# How to make a post to a server, wait on the response, then change the view based on response in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlsession

I am trying to verify the user of my app when they open the app. I have a splash screen that sends a post of the users email to the sever and based on the response from the server it will either load the home view or an email verification page.

The problem I get is that when I make the post it seems to put it on its own separate thread, and I do not see the response until the view already changed and the app has settled.

I have tried to use:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

and

```
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
         //more stuff to handle return 
        }
            task.resume()
```

and also

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest()
```

The problem with the first and third option is that they are deprecated methods, in addition to them working on their own thread, and receiving the response after the if statement changing the view already ran.

This is a snippet of the code being used:

```
        //returns the email of the user
        let email = self.fileCom.getUserStringField("email")


        //write the string to post to the server
        let post =  "email=" + email +
                    "&pass=" + self.serverCom.PASSWORD

        //post the user email to verification script and log result
        logResponse(self.serverCom.postToServer(self.serverCom.getVerifyEmailScriptURL(), bodyData: post))

        //Check the status of verified and email
       // if(self.fileCom.getUserBoolField("verified"))
        if(false)//temp
        {
            //change view to home view
            print("\nHomeView\n")
            showHomeView()
        }
        else
        {
            //change view to verification view
            print("\nVerifyView\n")
            showVerificationView()
        }
```

The if statement to change the view is based on the stored response from the server to the user file in the documents folder.

Comment: You have to show the view in the completion handler for the network call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLSession` is the current supported way to go here. With `NSURLSession` you can either create a class that implements its delegate methods to declare as its delegate, or you can use blocks/closures. "Blocks" in C/Obj-C closely map to "Closures" in Swift. They allow you to pass around functions as if they were variables. You can use `NSURLSession`'s `-dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` to accomplish this.

The completionHandler block will be executed (on the session's delegate queue) when the load completes. From there, you can act on the response.

Here is a quick example of using it (with some notes):

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
// Don't put other code before this next line, it is defining the closure we just started with the "{"
(data, response, error) -> Void in
    // This is where the closure body begins
    print(NSThread.isMainThread()) // false (unless you've set the delegate queue to be the main queue)

    // Example of processing the return value
    let dataString = NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(dataString) // Okay to do work with this here, but don't do any UI work.

    // Jump back over to the main queue to do any UI updates
    // UI updates must always be done on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print(NSThread.isMainThread()) // true (we told it to execute this new block on the main queue)
        // Execute the code to update your UI (change your view) from here
        myCoolUIUpdatingMethod(dataString)
    });

    // anything down here could be executed before the dispatch_async block completes
    // dispatch_sync would block this thread until its block completes
});

// run the task
task.resume()

// your program's main thread will not be blocked while the load is in progress
```

Comment: So I added this to my code, and it didn't run. I put a print statement before and after the "let task" line and only the print statement before it executed.

Comment: Also I added a task.resume() after the last ");" to make the task actually run. But it is still after the view changes.

Comment: I've just edited my post to clarify some things. If your second print statement was where I commented "Don't put other code before this next line..." that is why it didn't run. That is effectively inside the closure's header, which doesn't work. If you put a print inside "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {" where I have the second print to show it is the main thread, does that work?

Comment: Also, please note you should be triggering the view change from where I have the imaginary "myCoolUIUpdatingMethod()". That will ensure you have request response to run your logic on, and you are on the main thread.

Comment: When I put a sleep(4) before my if statement in my splash screen view controller, it allows the post response to be received.

Comment: Ok the myCoolUIUpdating makes sense,  I still used your example so I will mark this as correct, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Right, you want to decide which view to go to in that block, because it guarantees you have a response from the network. It is only called once the response is received. Relying on a response within 4 seconds is unstable, and will lead to unexpected behavior on slower networks. Additionally, using the sleep() function for anything (particularly on the main thread) isn't good. Your application will be unresponsive during that time, and if your application is unresponsive for too long, iOS will send an 0x8BADF00D exception, crashing your app.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the heads up, I guess i will move the change view code to there then instead. Thanks again